# itemfulfillment: sublist item field inventorydetail is not a subrecord field

Tags: netsuite

I want to do a bin `itemfulfillment` in netsuite.

But I can't get an example that works. When I run the below code I am receiving this error:

`Sublist item field inventorydetail is not a subrecord field`

I need to know what is the correct subrecord name to create an `itemfulfillment`

Thanks!

```
var sales_internalid = '2465';  //saleorderid 
    var einternalid = '110';  //employeeid
    var winternalid = '1';   //washsoueid
    var sinternalid = '6';  //itemid
    var quantity = 1;
    var displayname ='iphone'; 
    var shipgroup = 1;
    var salesOrder= nlapiCreateRecord('salesorder', sales_internalid, {recordmode: 'dynamic'});

    var obj = nlapiTransformRecord('salesorder', sales_internalid, 'itemfulfillment');
    obj.selectLineItem('item',1);
    obj.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item',  sinternalid );
    obj.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'location',  winternalid );
    obj.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', 1); 
    var subrecord= obj.editCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail');
    subrecord.selectLineItem('inventoryassignment', 1);
    subrecord.selectNewLineItem('inventoryassignment');
    subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'inventorynumber', '1');
    subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', '1');
    subrecord.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
    subrecord.commit();
    obj.commitLineItem('item');

    var fulfillmentOrderId = nlapiSubmitRecord(itemFulfillment, true);
```

Comment: Reviewed syntax

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when doing my first Inventory Transfer via code for a client. Turns out the Bin Number field is only a subrecord when the feature "Advanced Bin Management" is enabled. If the account you are working in is setup to just "Use Bins" then the Bin Number field on the line items of transactions is set via its text value. Example is in SS 2.0 but I believe it gets the point across:

```
            newRec = nsRecord.create({
                type: nsRecord.Type.INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENT,
                isDynamic: true
            });

            // In dynamic mode must set the subsidiary first.
            newRec.setValue({
                fieldId: bodyFields.subsidiary,
                value: locSub[datain.Location]
            });
            newRec.setValue({
                fieldId: bodyFields.adjustment_Location,
                value: datain.Location
            });
            newRec.setValue({
                fieldId: bodyFields.date,
                value: date
            });
            newRec.selectNewLine({
                sublistId: columnFields.type
            });
            newRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: columnFields.type,
                fieldId: columnFields.item,
                value: datain.Item
            });
            newRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: columnFields.type,
                fieldId: columnFields.adjust_Qty,
                value: datain.Quantity.toString()
            });
            if (parseFloat(datain.Quantity) > 0) { // If qty is positive must set the Est Unit Cost.
                itemVals = nsSearch.lookupFields({
                    type: nsSearch.Type.ITEM,
                    id: datain.Item,
                    columns: fields
                });
                cost = itemVals.averagecost || itemVals.lastpurchaseprice;
                newRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                    sublistId: columnFields.type,
                    fieldId: columnFields.est_Unit_Cost,
                    value: cost
                });
            }
            //
            // Format for binnumbers field is 'ValueText(qty)\rValueText(qty)\rValueText(qty)
            // the only exception is in cases of negative qty
            //
            binText = datain.Bin ? datain.Bin + '(' + datain.Quantity + ')' : '';
            newRec.setCurrentSublistValue({
                sublistId: columnFields.type,
                fieldId: columnFields.bin_Numbers,
                value: binText
            });
            newRec.commitLine({
                sublistId: columnFields.type
            });
            invRecResult.invRecId = newRec.save({
                enableSourcing: true,
                ignoreMandatoryFields: true
            });
```